# java - LuaJ: more than 3 arguments

Tags: java, luaj

Is there any possible to use more than three arguments in lua function?

Here is my piece of code:

```
LuaValue luaGlobals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
            luaGlobals.get("dofile").call(LuaValue.valueOf("./data/Actions/" + a_itemScript));

            LuaValue luaValLevel = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(a_level);
            LuaValue luaValPlayer = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(a_player);
            LuaValue luaValItem = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(a_thing);
            LuaValue luaValItemX = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(a_fromX);
            LuaValue luaValItemY = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(a_fromY);

            LuaValue luaOnUse = luaGlobals.get("onUse");

            if(!luaOnUse.isnil())
            {
                luaOnUse.call(luaValLevel, luaValItemX, luaValItemY);
            }
            else
            {
                a_parent.WriteInConsole("\nx Cannot Run Script: " + a_itemScript);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LuaValue.invoke() instead of LuaValue.call().  It takes a Varargs which can contain any number of arguments, and returns a Varargs containing all the return values:

```
Varargs results = luaOnUse.invoke(
    LuaValue.varargsOf(new LuaValue[] { 
        luaValLevel, luaValPlayer, luaValItem, luaValItemX, luaValItemY }));
```